# for list not working

Tags: arcpy, list, indentation

I'm trying to drop the `.shp` from my list but when I do and print, I am only seeing the last one. When I print the list from `ListFeatureClasses()` I am seeing all of them. Any thoughts?

Here is the code:

```
import arcpy

workspace = r"C:\Users\ChapmaT1\CountyFiles"
inputSpatialReference = r"C:\Users\ChapmaT1\Script\roads.shp"

#get SR of inputSpatialReference
inputSR = arcpy.Describe(inputSpatialReference)
toSpatialRef = inputSR.SpatialReference
toSpatialRefName = toSpatialRef.Name


#Set Up Workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace

#List of Shapefiles
shapefiles = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

#print shapefiles

#Good till Here########################################

for shape in shapefiles:
    shapeName = shape.replace('.shp', '')

print shapeName
```

---

The same can be seen using a non-ArcPy example (no `import arcpy` needed) of:

```
for shape in ["test1.shp","test2.shp","test3.shp"]:
    shapeName = shape.replace('.shp', '')

print shapeName
```

Comment: This is a Python rather than ArcPy issue because it is solely due to incorrect indentation.  I added a second test to your question to illustrate why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your last print statement is not indented properly. As it is now, your are calling it after, i.e not inside, the loop. To fix it, just put it inside the loop by adding enough space before.

```
for shape in shapefiles
   shapeName = shape.replace('.shp', '')
   print shapeName
```